# Can I create a SharePoint 2013 project in VS 2012 in Windows 7?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013

I read that for SharePoint 2013 will be able to create projects for SharePoint using Visual Studio installed on Windows 7 Does anyone know how to do it can or whether at all there is such a possibility? Or in VS 2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes u can create sharepoint 2013 projects

[Set up the development environment for SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx)

Pls go through this link for more details